# Thread.setPriority() is not working fine?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, jakarta-ee

i am just playing with threads. i am reading two text files a.txt and b.txt in multithreaded program.
what i am doing is that i am assigning higher priority to thread reading data from a.txt.
but this is not taking affect.
a.txt file gets read first or something unnormal is happeining.
plus a exception is also occurring.
anyone here to please help me.

**void main()**

```
package introtothreading;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class IntroToThreading {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
FileReaderA fa = new FileReaderA();
FileReaderB fb = new FileReaderB();
Thread t4 =  new Thread(fa);
Thread t5 =  new Thread(fb);
t4.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
t5.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t5.start();
t4.start();
}   
}
```

**FileReaderA**

```
 public class FileReaderA  implements Runnable
 {
File f = new File("D:/a.txt") ;
FileReader fr ;
BufferedReader br ;
public FileReaderA()
{
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);  
        br  =  new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileReaderA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {       
        String s;
        s = br.readLine();
        do
        {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = br.readLine();
        }
        while(! s.equals(""));
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception..");
    }
   }    
   }
```

**FileReaderB**

```
 public class FileReaderB implements Runnable
 {


 File f = new File("D:/b.txt") ;
 FileReader fr ;
 BufferedReader br ;
 public FileReaderB()
 {
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);  
        br  =  new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileReaderB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
    try {       
        String s1;
        s1 = br.readLine();
        do
        {
        System.out.println(s1);
        s1 = br.readLine();
        }
        while(!s1.equals(" "));
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception..");
    }
 }    
 }
```

**OutPut**

```
 run:
 1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at introtothreading.FileReaderB.run(FileReaderB.java:39)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
4-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
5-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
1-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
3-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
4-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
5-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
6-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
7-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
8-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
6-bbb
7-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
8-bbbbb
9-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)


**output2**


 1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 1-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 2-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 3-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 4-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 5-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 6-bbb
 7-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 8-bbbbb
 9-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 2-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 3-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 4-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 5-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 6-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 7-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 8-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at introtothreading.FileReaderB.run(FileReaderB.java:39)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

and my

***a.txt file contains***

1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

2-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

3-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

4-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

5-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

6-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

7-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

8-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

***b.txt file contains***

1-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

2-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

3-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

4-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb

5-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

6-bbb

7-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb

8-bbbbb

9-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Comment: This way of multithreading is deprecated in Java for quite a long time now. Please use threadpools and priority queues now.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that since the files are very small, they are read before there is even a context switch between threads. I suggest using much larger files to see a noticeable effect. Try copying the contents of the file until you have about 100Kb of data and you should see quite a difference.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because `readLine` returns null at the end of file, see [readline() returns null in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635032/readline-returns-null-in-java) .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, setting priorities in java threads is not a surefire way to execute one thing before another. Instead it's wiser to just establish a concrete happens-before relationship between events you want to occur in succession.

Your problem here is caused by the fact that the second you call start on t5 before calling it on t4. Though the priority of t4 is higher t5 is starter before t4 is and will almost definitely finish reading your file before your A file is read due to the fact that your computer has more than one processor.

Your exception is caused by the fact that you continuously read lines in your run method and compare them without first checking if they are null. use a while loop instead of a do while.

In the future use thread pools and queues and use the debugger to find out why your exceptions are being thrown.