# CODECHEF: Runtime Error (NZEC)

Tags: java, runtime-error

I attempted a problem from codechef and made my code on java which runs perfectly on eclipse on my laptop.But everytime i try to submit the code it gives me this NZEC error. 
Can anyone tell why am i getting  the non zero exit code error (NZEC) while i am executing this code.
Problem to this code: https://www.codechef.com/problems/STRPALIN

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Palindrome {

    public boolean check() throws IOException{
        String A;
        String B;
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        A=inp.readLine();
        B=inp.readLine();
        for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<B.length();j++)
            {
                if(A.charAt(i)==B.charAt(j))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        Palindrome M = new Palindrome();
        boolean[] array = new boolean[10];
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            array[i]=M.check();
        }
        for(int j=0;j<T;j++){
            if(array[j])
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `System.exit(0)` as the very last line you execute?

Comment: Always put your code inside `try` `catch` `block` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that while taking input from user for `String` A and B, the `readline()` method returns `null`, and when you try to access `String` A or B, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Hence the non-zero exit code .

Now, the `readline()` method returned `null` value because you created a `BufferedReader` object twice, which led to leakage of memory.

Refer to this link: [readline() returns null in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635032/readline-returns-null-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the NZEC error:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
 class Codechef {

    public boolean check() throws IOException{
        String A;
        String B;
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        A=inp.readLine();
        B=inp.readLine();
        for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<B.length();j++)
            {
                if(A.charAt(i)==B.charAt(j))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        try {
            Codechef M = new Codechef();
        boolean[] array = new boolean[10];
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            array[i]=M.check();
        }
        for(int j=0;j<T;j++){
            if(array[j])
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");

        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```